# Unity Build and Install Automatically to Multiple Androids

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Anyone knows what's the current best solution to build your game once on Unity and automatically getting it to install on to multiple Android devices?

[Edit]
I'm not talking about PlayStore distribution. My game is a multiplayer so to test it on my phones I need to install it on 4 phones 1 by 1 manually. I'm asking if there is an automatic process for that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is such a thing, you have to build it and then distribute it to other android devices by uploading the new update on the Play Store or give them the new apk, once you do they will get the update. Plus, I dont think Google would let you do that because they want the apps to be secured by them so the devices doesnt get infected with a virus. That is why they want to always review every single upload and update of your app, its to see if it does have a virus.

Comment: I'm not talking about PlayStore distribution. My game is a multiplayer so to test it on my phones I need to install it on 4 phones 1 by 1 manually. I'm asking if there is an automatic process for that.